# Can't make ultrasonic sensor work with motor controller

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, arduino-motor-shield

I just started using Arduino Uno, I can't get the ultrasonic to work ,with motor controller board, the output value is always zero.

Just to make sure I'm talking about the correct stuff:
I used this guide to try to make it work (look at the picture how did I connect the parts).

And this is my code:

```
#define trigPin A4//Attach Trig to port 8
#define echoPin A5//Attach Echo to port 7
#include <AFMotor.h>
//SMARS Demo 2 with Line sensor

AF_DCMotor R_motor(2); // defines Right motor pin
AF_DCMotor L_motor(1); // defines Left motor pin

int lmotorpin1 = 3;
int lmotorpin2 = 5;
int rmotorpin1 = 6;
int rmotorpin2 = 9;
int distancecm = 0;
//const int trigPin = 18;
//const int echoPin = 19;

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
void setup() {


  Serial.begin(9600); // sets up Serial library at 9600 bps

  //changes the following values to make the robot drive as straight as possible
  L_motor.setSpeed(200); // sets L motor speed
  R_motor.setSpeed(140); // sets R motor speed

  R_motor.run(RELEASE); //turns L motor on
  L_motor.run(RELEASE); //turns R motor on

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
}

void loop() {
      Serial.println(trigPin);
    Serial.println(echoPin);
  distancecm = mdistance();
  if (distance < 5) {
    L_motor.run(BACKWARD); //moves motor L Forward
    R_motor.run(FORWARD); //moves motor L Forward
//    delay(1000);
//    L_motor.run(FORWARD); //moves motor L Forward
//    R_motor.run(FORWARD); //moves motor L Forward
//    delay(1000);
  }
  else {
    L_motor.run(FORWARD); //moves motor L Forward
    R_motor.run(FORWARD); //moves motor L Forward
  }
}

int mdistance()
{
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Duration: ");
  Serial.println(duration);
  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

As you can see I tried different pin numbers but it always 0 ....

what do you think can be wrong?

The motors work.
Motor Controller: KEYES L293D Motor Control Shield
Sensor: Ultrasonic Ranger V2.0

Comment: and the motors work? do you have the shield?

Comment: what sensor are you using?

Comment: I added the info in the main post at the end

Comment: the way the description of your problem reads is `the ranger does not work with the motor controller, but it works without the motor controller` ..... is that what is happening?

Comment: I didn't check it without the motor controller.

Answer (score -1):

Pin numbers 0 and 1 are reserved for the Serial monitor which you're using on the board. 
The function `int mdistance()` should return an integer. 
You also didn't seem to set the motor pins as OUTPUT.

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment than actual solution to the OP's problem

Comment: Where is pins 0 and 1? I don't see why this is a problem because the motors are working.. The problem is the ultrasonic sensor.. Please explain yourself.

Comment: the motor number is not a pin number